# API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9946: 1006:: Abnormal Closure

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, websocket

I'm trying to connect local node running on my pc using `polkadot.js` library in react.js(browser). I'm pasting my code in below snippet and error that I'm facing in chrome console

**Code**

```
// ************************Polkadot****************************
import {WsProvider, ApiPromise} from '@polkadot/api';
import { ContractPromise } from '@polkadot/api-contract';
import { Keyring } from '@polkadot/keyring';
// ************************************************************
import bridgePeer from './MetaData/DevErc20Metadata.json';
import bridgeTxt from './MetaData/PrivErc20Metadata.json';


//Keyring for finding the private and public key pair
const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'ed25519' });

// Contract address and its host
const txtNode = new WsProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:9944');
 const PeerNode = new WsProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:9946');

const ContractAddressGxt = '5GDxmhbSFqoBbsdWC4qd7LLHMZNmW3xX4rLKA7Ucdgb6un4z';
const ContractAddressPeer = '5D6z8T8rWZW1Uy7RwPburZv4wo5tjhCtG8CbfR5pbgxSEY37';
let api1, api2;

(async () => {

  api1 = await ApiPromise.create({ provider:txtNode});
  api2 = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: PeerNode});

})();
```

**Console**

```
index.js:465 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9946/' failed: 
connect @ index.js:465
connectWithRetry @ index.js:499
WsProvider @ index.js:411
./src/Common/WasmWasmHelper.js @ WasmWasmHelper.js:15
options.factory @ react refresh:6
_webpack_require_ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/Componets/Swap/Swap.js @ loader.js:10
options.factory @ react refresh:6
_webpack_require_ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/App.js @ classPrivateFieldLooseKey.js:4
options.factory @ react refresh:6
_webpack_require_ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/index.js @ Swap.js:191
options.factory @ react refresh:6
_webpack_require_ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
logger.js:62 2022-06-10 18:36:55          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9946: 1006:: Abnormal Closure
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm facing this error any suggestion most welcome.

Comment: Are you running two nodes or why is the second port different?  
How did you start the nodes?

Comment: I am running both nodes on same system, that is why i need to have different ports.

Comment: And how did you start the nodes? Please provide the console commands, otherwise we cannot investigate this.

Comment: You'll definitely get this error if you happen to **not** have a substrate node running at all.

Comment: I've been getting this error when I continuously create new `ApiPromise` objects in polkadot-js in React. ```await ApiPromise.create({provider: ...});``` Is this bad practice and should I instead be sharing the `ApiPromise` object between my classes?

Comment: does it make any difference if you use `const [api1, api2] = await Promise.all([await ApiPromise.create({ provider:txtNode}), await ApiPromise.create({ provider: PeerNode})]);`

Answer (score 0):

`1006` can be an indication that no connection was made at all.

to debug whether or not your node is even listening on the port you expect to find it, tail the node logs to check for log messages like:

> Accepting new connection 1/100

> Accepting new connection 2/100

then attempt new connections from something that isn't previously untested code like [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat#installation). eg:

```bash
echo '{
  "id":1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "rpc_methods",
  "params":[]
}' | websocat -n1 -B 99999999 ws://127.0.0.1:9944
```

if you don't get a response to your websocat request, and you don't see new connections being made in the node logs, your problem is in the network layer. you may have a firewall or selinux setting blocking access to the port, the node may be listening on a non-default port (check your `--ws-port` node startup args) or ahy number of other things.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the node you are connecting to is out of connections.

This can be changed using `--ws-max-connections nnn` where *nnn* is the number of connections when starting the node.